# Vue-JS v-show Percitence in radio

Tags: vue.js

`v-show` appears not be percitent when whit radio (v-model)
Please find example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lngocxrj/1/

```
<div id="helloWorldApp">
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="true" name="optradio">hide
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="false" name="optradio">show
  <div v-show="visible">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <p>
   {{visible}}
  </p> 

</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldApp",
  data: {
    visible: true
  },
  methods: {
    show: function() {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean persistent?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because `visible` is storing the string value of `"true"` and `"false"`, and not boolean values itself. In this case, `"false"` is actually truthy because it is a string of non-zero length.

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you use a `method` to toggle the data.

HTML:

```
<div id="helloWorldApp">
  <label>hide<input type="radio" value="false" @click="inputClick(false)" name="optradio" /></label>
  <label>show<input type="radio" value="true" @click="inputClick(true)" name="optradio" /></label>
  <div v-show="visible">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <p>
    {{visible}}
  </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldApp",
  data: {
    visible: false
  },
  methods: {
    inputClick(val) {
      this.visible = val;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a new property to differentiate input changes and show/hide div

```
<div id="helloWorldApp">
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="true" name="optradio">hide
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="false" name="optradio">show
  <div v-if="showDiv">
    Hello Worlds
  </div>
  <p>
   {{visible}}
  </p> 

</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldApp",
  data: {
    visible: false,
    showDiv: true
  }, 
  watch: {
  visible(val) {
    this.showDiv = val;
  }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment: the reason why your element is showing regardless of the `v-show` directive is because the values from the checkboxes are being stored as strings and not booleans. And since `"false"` is actually truthy because it is a string of non-zero length, your div will always be visible.

### Quick solution: Perform string comparison

If you want to keep your code as-is, and understanding that you are looking at string values instead of boolean stored in `visible`, updating your template to use `v-show="visible === 'true'"` will work.

**Note:** I do not encourage this method though, because this is a code smell (see further below for a better solution).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldApp",
  data: {
    visible: 'true'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="helloWorldApp">
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="true" name="optradio">hide
              <input type="radio" v-model="visible" value="false" name="optradio">show
  <div v-show="visible === 'true'">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <p>
   {{visible}}
  </p> 

</div>
```

### A better solution: use checkbox for binary state toggling

This brings us to another issue: since you are toggling a property, a radio button is not the best UI to do that. A checkbox is more appropriate: in this case, you don't need to do dirty strict comparisons:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#helloWorldApp",
  data: {
    visible: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="helloWorldApp">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="visible" checked>visible
  <div v-show="visible">
    Hello World
  </div>
  <p>
    {{visible}}
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Terry the methods with checkbox is more elegant